# Java flow-control

Tags: java, control-flow

Can anyone explain why this code is giving output as null? When I try to call `new A()` instead of `new B()`, it is printing the current date.

```
class A
{
    Date d = new Date();

    public A()
    {
        printDate();
    }

    void printDate() 
    {
        System.out.println("parent");
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    Date d = new Date();

    public B()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    void printDate()
    {
        System.out.println("child");
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474521/allowing-the-this-reference-to-escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all inputs, I hope following answer satisfies,

As B also has field d, A.d is not inherited to B, where B has its own copy of d.

So when the control is in B.printDate(), it tries to look for A.d (because function is called from A).

this works fine if I remove following line from B

```
Date d = new Date();
```

Answer (score 4):

new B() invokes the constructor of B, which invokes the constructor of A. A's constructor calls `printDate()`, which, due to the overriding, executes B's `printDate()`, which prints the value of `d` variable of `B`. However, `d` variable of `B` is not initialized yet (it will only be initialized after the constructor of A is executed). Therefore it is still null (which is the default value for reference variables).

On the other hand, when you create an instance of `A` (`new A()`), `printDate` of `A` is called, and it prints the `d` variable of `A`, which was initialized prior to the constructor of `A` being executed.

In case it's not clear, B.d does not override A.d, it just hides it. Only methods can be overridden.

Comment: Are you sure? `B` also defines `d` which shadowes `d` from `A`

Comment: `A.d` is not visible from `B.printDate()`

Comment: @ooxi That's correct. This is the reason `printDate()` of B prints the `d` variable of B.

Comment: yes Eran, I have also same explanation, but my question is when i call new A(), at this time also constructor execution is not yet completed, so the d value should not be available in printDate(). there by it should print null. right.?

Comment: @ooxi you are correct. when I say "d" it is trying to get value from A. B has already its own copy of d, so it is not inherited d value from A.

Comment: @chiranjeevi in the first case, the init order is : member variables of A (A.d), constructor of A, member variables of B (B.d), constructor of B. In the second case : member variables of A (A.d), constructor of A. Therefore, in the second case A.d is already initialized when the constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Date` as **Static**

```
static Date d = new Date();
    public B(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    void printDate(){
        System.out.println("child");
        System.out.println(d);
    }
```

Comment: yeh, I know it works if I add static, but I want to know why my code is failing. and when I call new A() why it is not failing.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a `B`:

1. the B constructor chains to the A constructor
2. the A constructor calls `printDate`, but it is the `B.printDate` override that is called
3. the `B.printDate` prints `B.d`.
4. that gives `null` because the `B.d` field hasn't been initialized
5. the `printMethod` returns, and the `A` constructor returns
6. the fields of `B` are initialized, setting `B.d` to a non-null value.  But its too late to affect the output.

---

Some lessons to learn from this:

- It is a bad idea for a constructor to call an instance method on the object it is creating *unless* that instance method is either `private` or `final`.  If you manage to call a method that has been overloaded by a subclass, then that method will see the instance variables of the subclass **before they have been initialized** ... and that's problematic.
- It is a bad idea to use the same name for a (non-private) field in by a class and a subclass.  Both fields will exist, and it can be difficult for someone reading the code to keep it right in their head.
- Non-private instance fields are a bad idea.  They are bad for encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you call super() then the Date variable d defined in class A gets initialized. 
Since in class B the variable d is an object variable, and it overwrites the variable d from parent class, and object variables are constructed only after the `this` pointer is constructed, you are getting null.
If you want that to work as expected, make variable d in class B as static variable, which will then be initialized with class loading.