# Properly constructed objects

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, this

A properly constructed object is one that `doesn't let the this reference escape`.

I don't understand the above definition. I looked up a few posts on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513597/what-is-an-incompletely-constructed-object) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474521/allowing-the-this-reference-to-escape) but I don't understand what it means for the `this` reference to `escape`. Here is the example mentioned in the link :

```
public class ThisEscape {
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(
            new EventListener() {
                public void onEvent(Event e) {
                    doSomething(e);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Can someone in very simple words and plain manner explain how the `this` reference escapes here?

**EDIT**

@FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the question asks something entirely different. The questioner has asked, highlighted in bold by the questioner himself, how to protect against `this` reference escaping. I am asking what does it MEAN when it is said `this reference has escaped.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the question asks something entirely different. The questioner has asked, highlighted in bold by the questioner himself, how to protect against `this` reference escaping. I am asking what does it MEAN when it is said `this reference has escaped.

Comment: @VineetKaushik In the linked question/answer, there's a link to an article that clearly explains what it means to let the this reference escape