# Java escaping reference to 'this'

Tags: java, concurrency

I started reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://books.google.pl/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC) and I came across the following example (this is a negative example - shows bad practice):

```
public class ThisEscape {
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(new EventListener() {
            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                doSomething(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The author in the book writes:

> When ThisEscape publishes the EventListener, it implicitly publishes the enclosing ThisEscape instance as well, because inner class instances contain a hidden reference to the enclosing instance.

When I think about the usage of such code, I could do something like so:

```
EventSource eventSource = new EventSource();
ThisEscape thisEscape = new ThisEscape(eventSource);
```

and I can get the reference to the registered EventListener, but what does it mean that I could obtain the reference to the enclosing ThisEscape instance?

Could someone give me an example of such a behaviour? What is the use case?

Comment: Probably this could be an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084124/4563745

Comment: Ok, this is nice use case, but I still don't understand what is wrong with such escaping reference - even if I'd do ThisEscape.this.doSomething(); from within anonymous implementation, 'this' still stays visible within ThisEscape only.

Comment: The event source can send events before ThisEscape constructor has finished. The events will be processed with the object in an unpredictable state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing the this reference to escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474521/allowing-the-this-reference-to-escape)

Comment: I found another great explanation for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676796/how-does-this-reference-to-an-outer-class-escape-through-publishing-inner-clas?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with escaping this references is that code in other threads might start interacting with the object before the constructor is finished constructing it.

Consider this example:

```
public class ThisEscape
{
    Foo foo;
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(new EventListener()
        {
            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                doSomething(e);
            }
        });

        // Possible Thread Context switch

        // More important initialization
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    public void doSomething(Event e) {
        // Might throw NullPointerException, by being invoked
        // through the EventListener before foo is initialized
        foo.bar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem.Then I lookup the [whole code from the official site](https://jcip.net/listings/ThisEscape.java).You will understand naturally.The whole `ThisEscape` class looks like this:

```
package net.jcip.examples;

/**
 * ThisEscape
 * <p/>
 * Implicitly allowing the this reference to escape
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class ThisEscape {
    public ThisEscape(EventSource source) {
        source.registerListener(new EventListener() {
            public void onEvent(Event e) {
                doSomething(e);
            }
        });
    }

    void doSomething(Event e) {
    }


    interface EventSource {
        void registerListener(EventListener e);
    }

    interface EventListener {
        void onEvent(Event e);
    }

    interface Event {
    }
}
```

Notice that the `doSomething` method is part of the `ThisEscape` class, which means that another thread could potentially access the object through the `this` reference before the object has finished constructing itself.